# How can we transform other forms of linear equations into general linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

The straight line equation has oblique section: y==kx+m

Point-skew type: y-y0==k (x-x0)

Intercept type: x/a+y/b==1

Two-point formula: (x-x1)/(x2-x1)==(y-y1)/(y2-y1)

How to unify the above form into general equation form: Ax+By+c==0

The actual example is:

```
y==3x+6

x/3+y/6==1

y-8==2(x-3)

(x-2)/(7-2)==(y-1)/(9-1)

6x+8y+10==0

-x+7y+10==0
```

The above is unified into the form of Ax+By+C==0

The coefficient in front of x is required to be positive, and the constant terms of x and y are the simplest integers.

6x+8y+10==0  Its final result is   3x+4y+5==0

-x+7y+10==0   Its final result is   x-7y-10==0

Comment: Again, your choice of tags is confusing. Where are the differential equations? Also, this `y=3x+6` should have been `y==3x+6` and likewise for the rest

Comment: You could also use `CoefficientArrays`, see e.g. [185668](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185668/determining-the-coefficient-matrix). For instance `{1, x, y} . Flatten@CoefficientArrays[#, {x, y}] & /@ eqs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an expression f[x,y]==0, you may first simplify the equations and then  transform the equation into an expression by subtracting the left side from the right side.

The equations:

```
eqs = {y == 3 x + 6, x/3 + y/6 == 1, 
  y - 8 == 2 (x - 3), (x - 2)/(7 - 2) == (y - 1)/(9 - 1), 
  6 x + 8 y + 10 == 0, -x + 7 y + 10 == 0}
```

may be transformed by:

```
eqs= Simplify[eq] /. Equal -> Subtract 

{6 + 3 x - y, -6 + 2 x + y, 2 + 2 x - y, -11 + 8 x - 5 y, 
 5 + 3 x + 4 y, -10 + x - 7 y}
```

If you want to write them again in equation form:

```
(# == 0) & /@ eqs

{6 + 3 x - y == 0, -6 + 2 x + y == 0, 
 2 + 2 x - y == 0, -11 + 8 x - 5 y == 0, 
 5 + 3 x + 4 y == 0, -10 + x - 7 y == 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

For any equation `eq=A==B`, then `eq[[1]]` is `A` and `eq[[2]]` is `B`. This is the same as saying `First@eq` is `A` and `Last@eq` is `B`.

So `First@eq` is the left hand side of equation, and `Last@eq` is the right hand side of equation.

So to move all terms to one side of an equation, just do

```
 myNewEquation = First@eq - Last@eq == 0
```

Using the above

```
eqs = {y == 3 x + 6, x/3 + y/6 == 1, 
  y - 8 == 2 (x - 3), (x - 2)/(7 - 2) == (y - 1)/(9 - 1), 
  6 x + 8 y + 10 == 0, -x + 7 y + 10 == 0}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now do

```
((Expand[First[#] - Last[#]] == 0) & /@ eqs) // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`SubtractSides` can also be used if you prefer, but need to add `Simplify` for a reason I do not know yet. Like this

```
 (SubtractSides[Simplify[#]] & /@ eqs) // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we do the following, then one equation fail to be moved to one side. I do not know why. May be this needs separate question.

```
 SubtractSides /@ eqs // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]